# Cohen-Macaulay Analytic Rings

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, analytic-geometry, flatness, cohen-macaulay

Let $X \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be an affine Cohen-Macaulay variety. I would like to know whether for every point $p \in X$, the local ring of germs of analytic functions on $X$ at $p$ is also Cohen-Macaulay. A reference would be appreciated. Below I present my (rather long) attempt at a proof.

Let us assume that $p =0$ and write $R = \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]_{(x)}$ and $S = \mathbb{C}\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ (the ring of power series convergent in some polydisc around the origin). Since both are local and the embedding $R \to S$ is a map of local rings, we can apply the flatness criterion. Namely, $S$ is flat over $R$ if and only if $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(S,R/m) = 0$, where $m$ is the maximal ideal of $R$. Now a free resolution of $R/m$ is given by the Koszul complex and tensoring with $S$ it stays exact except for the rightmost term and we are done. So $S$ is flat over $R$. Now let $I \subset R$ be the ideal generated by the polynomials that vanish on $X$. So we have a commutative diagram:

$\begin{matrix} R & \rightarrow & S \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ R/I & \rightarrow & R/I \otimes_R S\end{matrix}$.

Since the upper arrow is flat, then so is the lower arrow. I believe that $R/I \otimes_R S$ is the ring of germs of analytic functions at the origin on $X$. Now choose a regular sequence that testifies to the fact that $R/I$ is CM. Tensoring the associated complex by $R/I \otimes_R S$ preserves cohomology, so the same sequence is regular in the ring of germs.

Comment: I am not really familiar with $S$ you described. However, of your $S$ is equal to $\mathbb{C}[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$, what you are claiming is correct. Tensoring with $S$ over $R$ is the $m = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$-adic completion.

Comment: The ring $S$ is the ring of convergent power series, namely it is the subring of the ring of formal power series. Those are the power series that converge in some polydisc around the origin. It is known that this is a regular Noetherian local ring of dimension $n$ (the number of variables).